# Email image is displaying above the table row in Outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email

I am having trouble getting the images to display correctly in Outlook for an email I am creating. In Outlook, the images are showing up clipped. When the image is clicked, you can see the outline handles of the image and the top two are positioned at the top of the table row above the row that contains the image. (Which is odd, since that row is in a parent table of the table with the image.)

I have tried all the normal fixes I found - setting the img to `display: block`, making the containing `<td>` have a line-height, I even set the height attribute to ensure there is enough space to render the image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I've added the wrapping html to the below code block. There is no other css outside of what is now posted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <!--<![endif]-->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title></title>
  <style>
  /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes. */
  body { 
   margin:0 !important;
   padding:0 20px;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; 
   -ms-text-size-adjust:none; 
  }
  img {
   border: 0;
  }
  div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] { 
   margin:0 !important;
  }
  .wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .outer {
   Margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 600px;
  }
  p {
   Margin: 0;
  }
  td.phone { display:none !important; }
  .contents td { font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; padding-top: 20px; width: 100%; }
  </style>
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
   <style type="text/css">
    table {border-collapse: collapse;}
   </style>
  <![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="bdy">
   <style type="text/css">
   <!--
    .x_full-width
     {width:640px}
    table.x_editor-body
     {width:100%}
    table.x_row
     {padding:0px;
     width:100%}
    table.x_row td.x_last
     {padding-right:0px}
    table.x_columns, table.x_column
     {padding-right:0;
     margin:0 auto}
    .x_el-button table.x_el-wrapper
     {border-collapse:separate}
    td.x_wrapper
     {padding:0}
    .x_hide-for-desktop
     {}
    .x_hide-for-desktop .x_hide-for-desktop .x_hide-for-desktop .x_hide-for-desktop 
     {}
    .x_loop-item > 
     {table-layout:auto}
    .x_editor-body
     {font-family:"Helvetica","Helvetica Neue","Arial",sans-serif;
     margin:0}
    .x_header-footer
     {margin:0}
    .x_valign
     {vertical-align:top}
    .x_no-padding
     {padding-right:0;
     padding-top:0;
     padding-bottom:0;
     padding-left:inherit}
    .x_row
     {word-break:break-word}
    .x_button
     {border:0;
     border-width:0;
     border-color:none;
     border-style:none;
     outline:0;
     display:block}
    .x_align-left
     {text-align:left}
    .x_align-right
     {text-align:right}
   -->
   </style>
   <style>
   <!--
    .x_wrapper
     {width:100%;
     table-layout:fixed}
    .x_outer
     {margin:0 auto;
     width:100%;
     max-width:600px}
    td.x_phone
     {}
    .x_contents 
     {font:13px/1.45em Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
     padding-top:20px;
     width:100%}
   -->
   </style>
   <div style="margin:0">
    <table class="x_editor-body" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; width:100%">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td style="padding:0" valign="top" align="center">
        <table class="x_import-message" style="font-size:16px; text-align:center; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; padding:10px; border-collapse:collapse" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td>
            <table class="x_row x_import-container x_import-container-5 x_import-container-99530235118" style="border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse; word-break:break-word; padding:0px; width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td class="x_wrapper x_valign" style="vertical-align:top; padding:0">
                <table class="x_columns x_import-column x_import-column-1" style="width:640px; border-collapse:collapse; padding-right:0; margin:0 auto" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                 <tbody>
                  <tr>
                   <td class="x_column-content x_valign x_no-padding" style="width:640px; vertical-align:top; padding-right:0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:inherit">
                    <table style="table-layout:fixed; border-collapse:collapse" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                     <tbody>
                      <tr>
                       <td class="x_import-element x_import-element-block x_import-element-1 x_import-element-45561606396" style="text-align:center; font-size:16px; padding:0; line-height:normal; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; width:640px" align="left">
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                         <table id="blockOrderEmailItems" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
                          <tr>
                           <td width="10" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td class="padding" width="620" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px; text-align: left;">
                            <table id="orderItemsWrapper" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
                             <thead style="background: #DEDEDE;">
                              <tr>
                               <th class="orderItemTitle" align="left" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; width: 270px; padding: 5px;">Item Name</th>
                               <th class="orderItemSku" align="center" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; padding: 5px;">Item Number</th>
                               <th class="orderItemQty" align="right" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-size: 16px; text-align: right; width: 40px; padding: 5px;">Qty</th>
                               <th class="orderItemPrice" align="right" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-size: 16px; text-align: right; width: 80px; padding: 5px;">Price</th>
                              </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>
                              <tr class="orderItemConfigurable" style="padding: 5px;">
                               <td class="orderItemTitle" align="left" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; width: 270px; padding: 5px;">
                                <a href="producutlink_here" style="color: #3696C2; text-decoration: underline solid #3696C2;">Fox Racing V2 Overseer Helmet</a>
                               </td>
                               <td class="orderItemSku" align="center" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; padding: 5px;">07120-001-XS</td>
                               <td class="orderItemQty" align="right" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: right; font-size: 16px; width: 40px; padding: 5px;">1</td>
                               <td class="orderItemPrice" align="right" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: right; font-size: 16px; width: 80px; padding: 5px;">
                                <span class="price">$179.97</span>
                               </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                               <td class="orderItemConfigurable" colspan="4" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 5px;">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                 <tr>
                                  <td class="padding" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px; text-align: left;">
                                   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                    <tr>
                                     <td width="145" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                       <tr>
                                        <td width="10" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td class="orderItemImage" width="125" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; width: 125px; line-height: 125px; text-align: left;">
                                         <img src="product_img_link_here" alt="Fox Racing V2 Overseer Helmet" width="125" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: 125px; height: 125px; display: block;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="10" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                      </table>
                                     </td>
                                     <td width="5" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                                     <td class="orderItemDetails" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                       <tr>
                                        <td style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                                         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                          <tr>
                                           <td colspan="2" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">Item Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;07120-001-XS</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                           <td colspan="2" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;Black</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                           <td colspan="2" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;XS</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                           <td colspan="2" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="price">$179.97</span></td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                           <td colspan="2" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
                                          </tr>
                                         </table>
                                        </td>
                                       </tr>
                                      </table>
                                     </td>
                                    </tr>
                                   </table>
                                  </td>
                                 </tr>
                                </table>
                               </td>
                              </tr>
                             </tbody>
                            </table>
                           </td>
                           <td width="10" style="font: 13px/1.45em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                         </table>
                        </div>
                       </td>
                      </tr>
                     </tbody>
                    </table>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </tbody>
                </table>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your style sheet so we can understand what values you set.

Comment: I tested your code and without a style sheet it displays fine in all email clients. If there's an issue, it's with your style sheet.

Comment: @gwally I've added the wrapping html and the css from the header to the original code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the reason I had a problem was due to setting the image containing  element to `mso-line-height-rule: exactly` and specifying a line-height on the image itself. When I reset the those  elements to `mso-line-height-rule: at-least` and removed the line-height from the  it displayed correctly.

A handy trick used in figuring this out, was using Outlook to save the email as html - but then using Word to open the html file. This displayed the email as it does in Outlook, but you can play around with the elements properties to see what needs changed to make it look like you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding this to the original question, but it keeps saying to body is too long

Here is what I get when I save the Outlook email as html:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=unicode">
 <meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
 <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14">
 <meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 14">
 <link rel=File-List href="ChapMoto%23%20100041953_files/filelist.xml">
 <link rel=Edit-Time-Data href="ChapMoto%23%20100041953_files/editdata.mso">
 <!--[if !mso]>
  <style>
   v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
  </style>
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <xml>
    <o:DocumentProperties>
     <o:Author>AUTHOR</o:Author>
     <o:Template>NormalEmail</o:Template>
     <o:Revision>1</o:Revision>
     <o:TotalTime>0</o:TotalTime>
     <o:Created>2018-07-27T21:48:00Z</o:Created>
     <o:Pages>1</o:Pages>
     <o:Words>1693</o:Words>
     <o:Characters>9655</o:Characters>
     <o:Company>Hewlett-Packard Company</o:Company>
     <o:Lines>80</o:Lines>
     <o:Paragraphs>22</o:Paragraphs>
     <o:CharactersWithSpaces>11326</o:CharactersWithSpaces>
     <o:Version>14.00</o:Version>
    </o:DocumentProperties>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
     <o:AllowPNG/>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  </xml>
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <xml>
    <w:WordDocument>
     <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
     <w:TrackMoves/>
     <w:TrackFormatting/>
     <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
     <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
     <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
     <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
     <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
     <w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>
     <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
     <w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
     <w:Compatibility>
      <w:DoNotExpandShiftReturn/>
      <w:BreakWrappedTables/>
      <w:SplitPgBreakAndParaMark/>
      <w:EnableOpenTypeKerning/>
     </w:Compatibility>
     <m:mathPr>
      <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"/>
      <m:brkBin m:val="before"/>
      <m:brkBinSub m:val="&#45;-"/>
      <m:smallFrac m:val="off"/>
      <m:dispDef/>
      <m:lMargin m:val="0"/>
      <m:rMargin m:val="0"/>
      <m:defJc m:val="centerGroup"/>
      <m:wrapIndent m:val="1440"/>
      <m:intLim m:val="subSup"/>
      <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"/>
     </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>
  </xml>
 <![endif]-->
 <style>
  <!--
   /* Font Definitions */
   @font-face
    {font-family:Helvetica;
     panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;
     mso-font-charset:0;
     mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
     mso-font-pitch:variable;
     mso-font-signature:-536859905 -1073711037 9 0 511 0;}
   @font-face
    {font-family:Helvetica;
     panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;
     mso-font-charset:0;
     mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
     mso-font-pitch:variable;
     mso-font-signature:-536859905 -1073711037 9 0 511 0;}
   @font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
     panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
     mso-font-charset:0;
     mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
     mso-font-pitch:variable;
     mso-font-signature:-536870145 1073786111 1 0 415 0;}
   /* Style Definitions */
   p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
     mso-style-qformat:yes;
     mso-style-parent:"";
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
     mso-style-priority:99;
     color:blue;
     text-decoration:underline;
     text-underline:single;}
   a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
     mso-style-priority:99;
     color:purple;
     text-decoration:underline;
     text-underline:single;}
   p
    {mso-style-noshow:yes;
     mso-style-priority:99;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.full-width, li.full-width, div.full-width
    {mso-style-name:full-width;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.hide-for-desktop, li.hide-for-desktop, div.hide-for-desktop
    {mso-style-name:hide-for-desktop;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
     display:none;
     mso-hide:all;}
   p.editor-body, li.editor-body, div.editor-body
    {mso-style-name:editor-body;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Helvetica","sans-serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.header-footer, li.header-footer, div.header-footer
    {mso-style-name:header-footer;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.valign, li.valign, div.valign
    {mso-style-name:valign;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.no-padding, li.no-padding, div.no-padding
    {mso-style-name:no-padding;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.button, li.button, div.button
    {mso-style-name:button;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.align-left, li.align-left, div.align-left
    {mso-style-name:align-left;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.align-right, li.align-right, div.align-right
    {mso-style-name:align-right;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     text-align:right;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.wrapper, li.wrapper, div.wrapper
    {mso-style-name:wrapper;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   p.outer, li.outer, div.outer
    {mso-style-name:outer;
     mso-style-unhide:no;
     margin:0in;
     margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:12.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
     mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
     mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;}
   span.price
    {mso-style-name:price;
     mso-style-unhide:no;}
   .MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
     mso-default-props:yes;
     font-size:10.0pt;
     mso-ansi-font-size:10.0pt;
     mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;}
   @page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
     margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;
     mso-header-margin:.5in;
     mso-footer-margin:.5in;
     mso-paper-source:0;}
   div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
  -->
 </style>
 <!--[if gte mso 10]>
  <style>
   /* Style Definitions */
   table.MsoNormalTable
    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
     mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
     mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
     mso-style-noshow:yes;
     mso-style-priority:99;
     mso-style-parent:"";
     mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
     mso-para-margin:0in;
     mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
     mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
     font-size:10.0pt;
     font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";}
  </style>
 <![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple style='tab-interval:.5in'>
<div class=WordSection1>
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt;align:center'>
 <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
  <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;padding-left:inherit'>
  <div align=center>
  <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt; border-spacing:0px;word-break:break-word'>
   <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td style='padding:7.5pt 7.5pt 7.5pt 7.5pt'>
    <div align=center>
    <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt;border-spacing:0px;word-break:break-word'>
     <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
      <td width="100%" valign=top style='width:100.0%;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;padding-left:inherit'>
      <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=640 style='width:480.0pt;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt;padding-left:inherit'>
       <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
        <td width=640 valign=top style='width:480.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
        <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt'>
         <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
          <td width=640 style='width:480.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
          <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
          <div align=center>
          <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt' id=blockOrderEmailItems>
           <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
            <td width=10 valign=top style='width:7.5pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
            <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
            </td>
            <td width=620 valign=top style='width:465.0pt;padding:0in 0in 15.0pt 0in'>
            <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt' id=orderItemsWrapper>
             <thead>
              <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
               <td width=270 style='width:202.5pt;background:#DEDEDE;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
               <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><b><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Item Name<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
               </td>
               <td style='background:#DEDEDE;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
               <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><b><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Item Number<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
               </td>
               <td width=40 style='width:30.0pt;background:#DEDEDE;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
               <p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:right;line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><b><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Qty<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
               </td>
               <td width=80 style='width:60.0pt;background:#DEDEDE;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
               <p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:right;line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><b><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Price<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </thead>
             <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>
              <td width=270 valign=top style='width:202.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
              <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><a href="productlink_here" style='text-decoration:solid #3696C2'><span style='color:#3696C2'>Fox Racing V2 Overseer Helmet</span></a> <o:p></o:p></span></p>
              </td>
              <td valign=top style='padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
              <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center;line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>07120-001-XS <o:p></o:p></span></p>
              </td>
              <td width=40 valign=top style='width:30.0pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
              <p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:right;line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>1 <o:p></o:p></span></p>
              </td>
              <td width=80 valign=top style='width:60.0pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
              <p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:right;line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span class=price><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>$179.97</span></span><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'> <o:p></o:p></span></p>
              </td>
             </tr>
             <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2'>
              <td colspan=4 valign=top style='padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
              <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt'>
               <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
                <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 15.0pt 0in'>
                <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt'>
                 <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
                  <td width=145 valign=top style='width:108.75pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                  <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                   <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
                    <td width=10 valign=top style='width:7.5pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                    <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width=125 valign=top style='width:93.75pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                    <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:93.75pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><img border=0 width=125 id="_x0000_i1026" src="product_img_link_here" style='-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display:block;height:125px;width:125px' alt="Fox Racing V2 Overseer Helmet"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
                    </td>
                    <td width=10 valign=top style='width:7.5pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                    <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                  <td width=5 valign=top style='width:3.75pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
                  </td>
                  <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                  <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt'>
                   <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
                    <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                    <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" style='width:100.0%;border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                     <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
                      <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                      <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Item Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;07120-001-XS<o:p></o:p></span></p>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>
                      <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                      <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;Black<o:p></o:p></span></p>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2'>
                      <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                      <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;XS<o:p></o:p></span></p>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:3'>
                      <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                      <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=price>$179.97</span> <o:p></o:p></span></p>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:4;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
                      <td valign=top style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                      <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;1<o:p></o:p></span></p>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td width=10 valign=top style='width:7.5pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
            <p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:17.4pt;mso-line-height-rule:exactly'><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
          <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";display:none;mso-hide:all'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";display:none;mso-hide:all'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran a Litmus test with your updated code and the images still display as expected.

If you're still experiencing problems, one fix I suggest is to wrap `""` around your values. As an example, instead of this (line: 289):

```
<div class=WordSection1>
  <table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt; border-spacing:0px;word-break:break-word'>
```

Try this:

```
<div class="WordSection1">
  <table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
  style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 15.0pt 0in 15.0pt; 
  border-spacing:0px;word-break:break-word">
```

Outlook is notoriously finicky when it comes to HTML code. This could be the reason you are having issues.

Good luck.